# Use a value of a query in a subquery

Tags: insert, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I'm trying to make a query that have a lot of subquerys (4 subquerys), but for the subquerys I need to take a value of the query, can anyone help me? This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.value1,
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(tab2.quantity) FROM tab2 INNER JOIN tab3 ON tab2.id_tab2 = tab3.id_tab2 INNER JOIN tab4 ON tab3.id_tab3 = tab4.id_tab3 WHERE tab4.value = "value1"), 0) AS v1,
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(tab2.quantity) FROM tab2 INNER JOIN tab3 ON tab2.id_tab2 = tab3.id_tab2 INNER JOIN tab4 ON tab3.id_tab3 = tab4.id_tab3 WHERE tab4.value = "value2"), 0) AS v2
```

What I need to do is that in the subquerys, make an INNER JOIN with that value1 the subquery make the adding but just with the values that are of the value1, because right now the subquery make the add of all the values located in the table that are equal with "value1" or "value2", I have tryed to make a subquery like these:

```
ISNULL((SELECT SUM(tab2.quantity) FROM tab2 INNER JOIN tab3 ON tab2.id_tab2 = tab3.id_tab2 INNER JOIN tab4 ON tab3.id_tab3 = tab4.id_tab3 INNER JOIN tab5 ON tab2.id_tab5 = tab5.id_tab5 INNER JOIN tab1 ON tab5.id_tab1 = tab1.id_tab1 INNER JOIN tab1 ON tab1.value1 = tab1.value1 WHERE tab4.value = "value1"), 0) AS v1
```

But obviously it didn't function, I also have tried to use an allias for the value1 but it says that it doesn't exist, anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to take a stab at it... It looks like you are trying to join the four tables by `_id` and aggregate a sum based on the child table's (`tab4`) value.

In the below example I used three tables, but the idea is the same. If this doesnt meet your needs perhaps you can repurpose this example to clearly define your requirements:

```
declare @tab1 table (i int primary key, value varchar(10));
insert into @tab1
    select 1, 'one' union all select 2, 'two'

declare @tab2 table (i int primary key, quantity varchar(10));
insert into @tab2
    select 1, 10 union all
    select 2, 20

declare @tab3 table (i int primary key, value varchar(10));
insert into @tab3
    select 1, 'value1' union all
    select 2, 'value2'


select  t1.value,
        sum(case when t3.value = 'value1' then t2.quantity else 0 end),
        sum(case when t3.value = 'value2' then t2.quantity else 0 end)
from    @tab1 t1
join    @tab2 t2 on t1.i = t2.i
join    @tab3 t3 on t2.i = t3.i
group
by      t1.value;
```

Comment: Basically what you're doing is to make the subquerys and save them in temporal tables and then make the query joining it with the value of the table1?

Comment: No, I am using table variables (@tab1) here in place of your physical tables. You should be able to take my query and point it at your real tables

Comment: Thanks! It really function! But I have a question, if I put the query in a string in Java, it will work?

Comment: Yes, if you are querying MSSQL I dont see why it would not work